# Drag and Drop not working with external monitor

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms

I'm working on a small project for my studies. It's the first contact with SQL in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition for me.

My study documents say that I can drag a table from the data sources window onto a form and a DataGridView would appear. That doesn't work. So I changed the property of the table from DataGridView to Details.

According to the documents from my university it should now add a TextBox with a Label for every row in the table.

Guess what? That won't work either. The cursor changes to the "Drop here" symbol, but if I drop the element onto the form nothing happens.

There is no error message or something like that.

[Here's a pic of the cursor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Vgp.png) Looks good for me. [I'm connected to the db as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r7ud.png) It's a database file on my computer, so there can't be connectivity problems.

Google and the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/bind-windows-forms-controls-to-data-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) didn't help me with that.

Maybe someone else can? :)

Comment: Working with Visual Studio and with Windows Forms Applications is not new to me. It's the the combination of Windows Forms Application AND a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to your answer...
I can't test this on my machine...but I think its worth a try.

> Goto Tools->Options Environment->Preview Features.
> Check
> Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities
> (requires restart)
> **In VS2019...**
> Goto Tools->Options->Environment->General
> Check
> Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities
> (requires restart)

Also...be sure your on the latest version...there were issues on some of the preview versions.

Comment: It really sounds good, but neither checked nor unchecked there was any difference. I found it @ Options -> Environment -> General. I'm on the actual version 16.4.3

Comment: @Shendayan Oh well it was worth a try...Im going to delete this answer in a few..

Comment: If you don't mind, leave it there. Maybe it helps someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh my gosh... It's an issue with my external monitor.

If I'm dropping the table onto the form, while Visual Studio is displayed on my external monitor (Resolution 1920*1080) it won't work.

If i drop it onto the form, while Visual Studio ist displayed on the build in screen of my Surface Book 2 (Resolution 3000*2000), it works like a charm.

How the heck should somebody know this? Thanks for reading the question anyway...

Comment: how are you sure that it is monitor issue? i have 2 monitors 1 full hd it works another 4k, i have exactly this problem on 4k monitor. I use Rider side by side and on Rider it works fine on both monitors